# Triac never switch off

Tags: triac

I designed this circuit;

[image]

PRI_LO and NEUT are connected to 220v.
The "high side" triac is Q4004D3RP ([datasheet](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/2183293.pdf?_ga=2.263085067.685827341.1582798795-246629436.1569588102)).

I measure voltage at J2.

Whatever is the command signal, I always measure 220v. I shorted the led of the MOC3041, same result. Why?

Second question, this system is triggered by an esp32. During a test, I unplugged the usb cable of the ESP32 and I noticed some electric arc on 220v side. I was unable to see exactly where. At this moment a smartphone charger was plugged in J2. Why?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> I always measure 220v. Why?

Your measurement meter has an input impedance of around 10 Mohms and the leakage of the triac might be equivalent to 100 kohm so, this means you'll see about 99% of the AC voltage on your meter when the triac is deactivated.

But, you also have a snubber that conducts electricity and that has an impedance of around 32 kohm at 50 Hz. Do the math.

> Why?

Your *why* question doesn't really constitute a sensible question. For example: -

```
At this moment a smartphone charger was plugged in J2. Why?
```

Not sensible to ask.

```
I was unable to see exactly where. Why?
```

Not sensible to ask.

Do you see what I mean?